# Turn to automation QA process

Tags: automated-testing, test-design, qa-developer

I am a manula QA. But i want to turn to automation QA process, i select  Selenium(IDE, RC, WebDriver)as Functional Testing Tools. but i want help for learn this ID quickly.

so anybody knows recommented tutorial or vedio for that.

Comment: This is going to be very difficult to answer. What I strongly recommend is you just do whatever you can. Try to tackle a problem that you think might be easy (compared to the rest) and still have a lot of benefit to your automation process. When you run into trouble, ask a new question. Specific questions are much, much easier and more helpful to everyone than broad ones!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are the things you could start of with :

1. Choose the language in which you will implement your Selenium scripts from among Java, Python, Ruby, Perl, PHP, Javascript, etc. Learn one if you don't know. You don't need to be a real master to get started but the more you know the easier it will get to perform advanced operations in your scripts.
2. Refer to the [Selenium docs](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/) to get a good feel of what it actually is like.
3. There are many books to get you started such as Selenium Cookbook, Selenium Simplified and others. All are available on leading e-stores so should be easily accessible.
4. Search the internet, there's loads of content on wonderful sites. Unfortunately my reputation isn't high enough to post more than one hyperlink otherwise I would have posted them here.

These are the steps I have followed and found to be effective. There's loads of more things one can do, refer to other content but this should be sufficient to get you started and should give you a rough idea as to how to approach.